# Create Cookie Array that never expires with JS/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, cookies

I have a website with quotes and want users to be able to favourite quotes clicking on a star-icon. I have this code:

```
jQuery('.fav').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this).parent();
    var id = $this.attr("data-id");

    // Build the expiration date string:
    var expiration_date = new Date();
    var cookie_string = '';
    expiration_date.setFullYear(expiration_date.getFullYear() + 1);
    // Build the set-cookie string:
    cookie_string = "fav="+id+"; path=/; expires=" + expiration_date.toGMTString();
    // Create/update the cookie:
    document.cookie = cookie_string;
});
```

But this only saves one cookie "fav=id". I wanted to create a cookie array where all quotes that will be clicked are saved with their id in the cookie array "fav", so I could show a list to the user of all saved quotes. How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to write the array

```
var cookieArray= {};
cookieArray[id] = true; //or whatever value
var stringifiedArr = JSON.stringify(cookieArray);
$.cookie("favs",stringifiedArr , { path: '/' });
```

to read the cookie

```
var arrFromCookie = $.cookie("favs");
var favsCookieData = JSON.parse(arrFromCookie);
```

Comment: Thank you, I can now store it, but the cookie gets overwritten each time I click. Why doesn't it add new values to a existent cookie instead of overwriting it?

Comment: so just parse it before you update and update the array before stringifying again

Answer (score 0):

Use the JSON.stringify() and JSON.parse() methods to store an array or an object as a string in the cookie and to retrieve it later.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies only can hold as strings. If I would like to simulate an array I will to serialize it and deserialize it. Can use [Json](http://json.org/) library